# How do i reference other blogpost in a blog content - drupal 7 with views

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I create blog posts in drupal 7 with the module "view" to display the content items as a blog.
However I would like to be able to reference old posts inline so as to reuse content and add traffic.
But my current workflow is to go and look at the old post and copy the url, like it was an external link.

This seems quite silly to do internal and would also break links if links changed.

How can I add these dynamically instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two plugins does the trick:

- [CKeditor link](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor_link) - if you use the ckeditor
- [LinkIt](http://drupal.org/project/linkit/) integreates into other wysiwyg modules